# SQL: Select rows with column values occurs n times and insert rows with that value

Tags: mysql, sql-server, python-2.7

Suppose that I have a table "employee" with two columns: "id" and "name"

```
id     | name    
---------+-------  
   3     | Clinton
   5     | Gates
   3     | Bush
   7     | Clinton
   7     | Obama
```

I would like to insert row with id(occurs 2 times in employee table) and with any name.

Actually I want to write a python script to get ids occurs n times in table(2 rows table) and insert more rows in that table with those ids in first column and hard coded name in other column.

for ex: output for able table should be

```
id     | name    
---------+-------  
   3     | Clinton
   5     | Gates
   3     | Bush
   7     | Clinton
   7     | Obama
   3     | john
   7     | tom
```

Comment: how you will get random name, where are that name. can we add constant string like `xyz`

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't provide enough information here. We are pretty good at t-sql but most of us are pretty awful at mind reading. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

This query is a good start with SQL Server despite the lack of info in the question:

```
declare @table table(id int, name varchar(50));
Insert into @table(id, name) values
(3, 'Clinton')
, (5, 'Gates')
, (3, 'Bush')
, (7, 'Clinton')
, (7, 'Obama');

With names(name, id) as (
    Select name, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by nid) From (
        Select distinct name, nid =  NEWID() From @table
    ) as n
)
Select ids.id, n.name From (
    Select t.id, n = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 1))
    From @table t
    Inner Join (Select name From @table Group By name Having COUNT(*) > 1) d on d.name = t.name
) as ids
Inner Join names n on n.id = ids.n;
```

Since I don't know where the random names come from, I reuse the main name table.
The CTE randomly order the name from 1 to 5. This value is then use to join with the duplicates and give a ramdom output such as:

```
id  name
7   Bush
3   Obama
```

Answer (score 0):

use `HAVING`

```
declare @temp table
(id  int, name nvarchar(33))

insert into @temp values (3,'Clinton')
insert into @temp values (5,'Gates  ')
insert into @temp values (3,'Bush   ')
insert into @temp values (7,'Clinton')
insert into @temp values (7,'Obama  ')
```

**Way1:** you can use constant string like that `XYZ`

```
insert into @temp
select id,'XYZ' from @temp 
group by id
having COUNT(id) = 2

select * from @temp
```

**Way2:** you can generate random string using `NEWID()`

```
insert into @temp
select id, CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()) from @temp 
group by id
having COUNT(id) = 2

select * from @temp
```